# Unable to open password protected pdf in angular application

Tags: angular, pdf, password-protection, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

i use **pdfjs-dist** in my angular application to render pdf. but i am unable to open password protected pdf.
Is there any other way to verify password for the document and open it.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: i use getDocument function of pdfjs-dist like that getDocument(fileData, null, '12345') here '12345' is a password of my pdf file

Comment: getDocument(fileData) is working for normal pdf but unable to open password protected pdf

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.

```
let  pdfJs= require('pdfjs-dist');
pdfJs.getDocument({ url: 'my.pdf', password: 'your password' }).then(function(pdf) 
{
  let text = [];
  for(let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
    pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
      page.getTextContent().then(function(data) {
        for(let j = 0; j < data.items.length; j++) {
          text.push(data.items[j].str);
        }        
      });
    });
  }

}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

Comment: Now i am able to open password protected file by this code                                      `selectedDoc.onPassword = function (validatePassword, reason) {
            let password;
            if (reason === 1) {
                password = prompt('enter a password:');
                validatePassword(password);
            }
            else {
                password = prompt('Invalid! enter a password:');
                validatePassword(password);
            }
        };`